# How to limit concurrent threads running in c and get return value of each thread after it finishes executing (pthread)

Tags: c, pthreads

I would like to limit to amount of concurrent threads when using the pthread_create() function.

In my application now, i am currently starting a bunch of threads using pthread_create() but have no way of limiting the number of concurrent threads currently running in my program.

A thread pool is ok but i would like keep my program as simple as possible.

I know that if you do use a thread pool, you would need some sort of manager thread for it and in my current program i need the return value of each thread when it finishes running and i am not too sure on how a thread pool will help me in this as libraries such as https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool do not have a way to get the return value of each thread after it finishes executing.

My current program uses pthread_join() to get the value back of each threads once it finishes executing.

Any ideas?

Comment: A thread pool does not require a manager thread.  A pool is commonly implemented as a producer-consumer queue upon which a,fixed number of work threads wait for pointers to 'task' structs that contain fields for arguments, results and a function pointer to the code that a work thread .just run, (with the task as an argument).  The task can contain an event, condvar, semaphore or completion routine pointer for signalling task completion.

Comment: Continual create/terminate/destroy of threads with create/join is not particularly simple, wastes loads of resources on the avoidable create/destroy, is very prone to errors/bugs and is just about the worst possible way to make use of multiple threads.  It is taught first in classes and/or tutorial sites because reasons, chief of which, I suspect, is that the authors of such learning resources are clueless:(